# How to explain the portion of the hand that holds less than the other?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you hold a handful of something, the enclosed portion below your thumb can generally handle a larger quantity than the area circled red in the photo below...

[image]

How can this less-supported area be briefly described (if there isn't a single word for it)?

For example, here's what I quickly came up with: *I grip [the coins] harder, losing one from the unfortunately large exposure where three more fingers next to my thumb would benefit me greatly.* haha!

Comment: Isn't that just the *palm*? Or are you talking about the portion (of 3D space) above the palm but outside the closed fist?

Comment: No, the palm is "the inner surface of the hand between the wrist and fingers," which is the entire flat part of your hand. Yes, I'm asking about the 3D space.

Comment: Based on [this site (click on figure 1)](http://www.intechopen.com/books/new-trends-and-developments-in-biometrics/basic-principles-and-trends-in-hand-geometry-and-hand-shape-biometrics), it's the space near the *hypothenar* and *lower palm*. I'm not sure that space has a name. You didn't ask about the space that "can generally handle a larger quantity", but the name of that space might lead to the name of the space you're looking for - what do you call that 'larger quanitity' space?

Comment: "butt of your hand"

Comment: Wait what? Clearly that's the portion of the hand that holds *the most*. There's only so much space under my thumb. While the circled area is *my whole friggen hand*. So confused right now.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Rather, "_over_ the butt of your hand". You don't lose a coin from the butt when you grip on coins, but from the exposure right above the butt.

Comment: Are you referring to the basal joint (base of the thumb/palm)?